# Complex algebra

Tags: algebra

I give Mathematica these commands:

```
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals]
\[Theta] = ArcTan[x, y]
z = Exp[I \[Theta]]
Conjugate[z]
```

I get

```
E^(-I Conjugate[ArcTan[x, y]])
```

How do I get Mathematica to recognize that `ArcTan[x,y]` is real?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) and [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), Note that [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) is only used by functions that use the option [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html)

```
$Assumptions = Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals];
θ = ArcTan[x, y];
z = Exp[I θ];
Conjugate[z] // 
  ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // Simplify

(* (x - I y)/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] *)
```